# AutoRunning a macro in PowerShell which is executed in the task scheduler

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have written an Excel macro.
Now I want to call this macro through a PowerShell Script and store it in the task scheduler.

My Script:

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$excel.AutomationSecurity = 1

$excel.Application.Run("'C:\Users\testuser\Documents\test.xlsm'!Module1.Start_All")

$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

$excel.Quit()

[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

This script works fine as long as I run it manually.
If there are any suggestions for improvement I will gladly accept them.

What does not work is the task scheduling:

- Start a program
- Program: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
- Arguments: -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NonInteractive -File C:\Users\testuser\Documents\TestMacro.ps1

If I run the PowerShell script via the TaskScheduler, I don't get an error message but the TaskScheduler tells me it is running the task and nothing happens.
In the Task Manager I can see that Excel is running but with 0% load.

Does anyone have an idea what this is?

Comment: A common error is that the task is not run for the currently logged on user. Then it runs in a service account, which can cause various problems, e. g. a GUI application can't create windows and doesn't have access to the user's profile. Make sure "Run only when the user is logged on" is checked in the task settings. Also make sure your script doesn't refer to the current directory, which might not be what you expect, when running as scheduled task. E. g. use `"$PSScriptRoot\Filename"` to refer to a file in the script directory using an absolute path instead of relative path `".\Filename"`.

Comment: The current task is running for the correct user. I can also see that the domain admin can run the task without any problems and there are no issues. Now I have checked the individual paths in my macro and found that all paths are absolute and that the respective user also has the appropriate permissions. I dont know why the script wont run for this specific user.

Comment: I have found the error:
Under the specific user I had to allow the office settings like all macros and disable warnings.
Now it runs through =)